# How to do password rotation through secrets manager for RDS MySQL aurora?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-secrets-manager

I have secrets manager with the secret value url in following format:
 `mysql+pymysql://username:password@db-name-dbcluster-13aaj5jwbujqa.cluster-cim1u06sewzq.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com/`

I want to automatically rotate the password and have two users , so there is no downtime as well.

I tried using was multi user rotation lambda function in sample code provided but it doesn't fit my needs as they need in following format :

```
        'engine': <required: must be set to 'mysql'>,
        'host': <required: instance host name>,
        'username': <required: username>,
        'password': <required: password>,
        'dbname': <optional: database name>,
        'port': <optional: if not specified, default port 3306 will be used>,
        'masterarn': <required: the arn of the master secret which will be used to create users/change passwords>
    }
```

I do not have master Arn in my secrets value.

I would like to have my custom lambda function which will to automatic rotation of password using secrets manager and with two user, so it swaps user 1 to user 2 during rotation.

Comment: Fix the Lambda function code to work with the secret format you have, or change the secret to the format expected by the Lambda.